# Assistance with PHP edit on a Wordpress Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am fairly new to php and have tried my hand thus far, unsuccessfully, to make the necessary edits to a WordPress theme (OneTone by MAGEEWP http://www.mageewp.com/onetone-theme.html)which would allow me to replace a youtube video with a slider plugin.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[smartslider2 slider="1"]');?>
```

Essentially I would need to add to add a condition or boolean statement to index.php in which, for example, if the “Section Background Video” field in WP is set to “slider” then

```
echo do_shortcode(‘[smartslider2 slider="1"]‘);
```

(so that a slider would display in the section-banner .css class rather than a youtube video specified in the Wordpress control panel).

This seems like it shouldn't be a terribly difficult modification, however I am a bit out of my depth in actually editing the php. any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Below is the code from index.php

```
<?php

/**

* The main template file.

*

*/

 ?>

<?php

if ( 'page' == get_option( 'show_on_front' ) && ( '' != get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ) && $wp_query->get_queried_object_id() == get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ) {

get_header("site");

?>

<div class="site-main">

        <div class="main-content">

            <div class="content-area">

                <div class="site-content" role="main">

                    <header class="archive-header">

                        <h1 class="archive-title"><?php onetone_get_breadcrumb();?></h1>

                    </header>

                    <?php if (have_posts()) :?>

                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 



                        get_template_part("content","article");

                    ?>

                   <?php endwhile;?>

                   <?php endif;?>



                    <nav class="paging-navigation">

                        <div class="loop-pagination">

                            <?php if(function_exists("onetone_native_pagenavi")){onetone_native_pagenavi("echo",$wp_query);}?>

                        </div>

                    </nav>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <!--main--> 



        <div class="sidebar">

            <div class="widget-area">

        <?php dynamic_sidebar(1) ;?>

            </div>

        </div>

        <!--sidebar--> 

    </div>

<?php

get_footer("site");

}else{

?>



<?php 

get_header();

?>

<div class="container home-wrapper">

<?php



 $video_array = array();

 $section_num = onetone_options_array( 'section_num' ); 

 if(isset($section_num) && is_numeric($section_num ) && $section_num >0):

 for( $i = 0; $i < $section_num ;$i++){



 $section_title       = onetone_options_array( 'section_title_'.$i );

 $section_menu        = onetone_options_array( 'menu_title_'.$i );

 $section_background  = onetone_options_array( 'section_background_'.$i );

 $section_background_video  = onetone_options_array( 'section_background_video_'.$i );

 $section_css_class   = onetone_options_array( 'section_css_class_'.$i );

 $section_content     = onetone_options_array( 'section_content_'.$i );

  if(!isset($section_content) || $section_content=="") $section_content     = onetone_options_array( 'sction_content_'.$i );

 $section_slug        = onetone_options_array( 'menu_slug_'.$i );



 $background = onetone_get_background($section_background); 

 $sanitize_title = "";

 if($section_menu  && $section_menu  != ""){

 $sanitize_title = sanitize_title($section_menu );

 if(trim($section_slug) !=""){

     $sanitize_title = $section_slug; 

     }

 }

 $css_class = isset($section_css_class)?$section_css_class:"";



  $background_video = '';

  $video_wrap = '';

  $video_enable = 0;

  $detect = new Mobile_Detect;

  if($section_background_video != "" && !$detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet()){

    $video_enable = 1;  

  }



 if($video_enable == 1){



    $background_video  = array("videoId"=>$section_background_video, "start"=>3 ,"container" =>"section.onetone-".$sanitize_title,"playerid"=>$sanitize_title);

    $video_section_item = "section.onetone-".$sanitize_title;

    $video_array[]  =  array("options"=>$background_video,  "video_section_item"=>$video_section_item );

    $background = "";

    $video_wrap = "video-section";

    }



 ?>

 <section class="section <?php echo $css_class;?> onetone-<?php echo $sanitize_title;?> <?php echo $video_wrap;?>"  style=" <?php echo $background; ?>">

        <div class="home-container page_container" >

        <?php if($section_title){?>

            <h1><?php echo $section_title;?></h1>

            <?php } ?>

            <?php echo do_shortcode($section_content);?>

        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>

     <?php 

      if($video_enable == 1){

      echo '<p class="black-65" id="video-controls">

          <a class="tubular-play" href="#"><i class="fa fa-play "></i></a>&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

          <a class="tubular-pause" href="#"><i class="fa fa-pause "></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

          <a class="tubular-volume-up" href="#"><i class="fa fa-volume-up "></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

          <a class="tubular-volume-down" href="#"><i class="fa fa-volume-off "></i></a> 

      </p>';

     }

     ?>

    </section>

 <?php



 }

  if($video_array !="" && $video_array != NULL ){

  wp_localize_script( 'onetone-bigvideo', 'onetone_bigvideo',$video_array);



        }



 endif;

 ?>

<div class="clear"></div>  

</div>

<?php get_footer();}?>
```

There are fields in WP which correspond directly with the variables defined below:

```
 $section_title       = onetone_options_array( 'section_title_'.$i );

 $section_menu        = onetone_options_array( 'menu_title_'.$i );

 $section_background  = onetone_options_array( 'section_background_'.$i );

 $section_background_video  = onetone_options_array( 'section_background_video_'.$i );

 $section_css_class   = onetone_options_array( 'section_css_class_'.$i );

 $section_content     = onetone_options_array( 'section_content_'.$i );

  if(!isset($section_content) || $section_content=="") $section_content     = onetone_options_array( 'sction_content_'.$i );

 $section_slug        = onetone_options_array( 'menu_slug_'.$i );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.  Change:

```
if($section_background_video != "" && !$detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet()){
    $video_enable = 1;  
}
```

to:

```
if($section_background_video == "video" && !$detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet()){
    // this assumes that the value is 'video' if a video is desired.  replace that with whatever it should be.
    $video_enable = 1;  
} else($section_background_video == "slider" && !$detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet()){
    // let's use a value of 2 to signify the slider
    $video_enable = 2;  
}
```

Then down below:

```
if($video_enable == 1){

  // no changes here

} elseif($video_enable == 2){
  echo do_shortcode(‘[smartslider2 slider="1"]‘);
}
```